# Am I using Underscore's throttle method correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, underscore.js, flot

I am trying to create a draggable line in a graph via Flot. I have a function that accomplishes that and executes on Flot's Plothover event (which is similar to a mouseMove event) when a certain boolean is true.  The function gets called continuously and this has caused the resulting animation to lag significantly.  To solve this I tried two approaches:

First I tried using setTimeout.  This helped the function run better, but I was unsatisfied.  The animation began to lag again if the webpage was left open for more than a minute, I have no idea why.  If anyone knows whats up with that any insight would be appreciated.

Second, I tried Underscore's throttle function.  I am a little unsure of the syntax, and after some research and debugging this is what I settled on.  The following code is inside the event handler:

```
var throttled1 = _.throttle(singleLine, 50);
throttled1(position);
```

Where singleLine is the following function, defined outside the event handler:

```
function singleLine(position) {
      adjustLine1[0] = [position, Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY];
      adjustLine1[1] = [position, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY];
      graphData.push({ data: adjustLine1, lines: { show: true }, color: "gray" });
      plot.setData(graphData);
      plot.draw();
      graphData.pop();
}
```

Keep in mind plot.draw() is a pretty long function (it redraws the entire graph).  Anyway, it appears to work because singleLine is successfully called by throttled1(position).  However, it is not improving performance at all.  Am I using it correctly?  Any other insights into how to make this run better are also welcomed.  Thanks.

Comment: Do you have `var throttled1 = _.throttle(singleLine, 50);` inside your Plothover event listener, or outside. In other words: is `var throttled1 = _.throttle(singleLine, 50);` called once per event or only one time for the all application ? (Should not be once per event)

Comment: Inside the Plothover event.  So yes, it does run once per event.  I will move `var throttled1 = _.throttle(singleLine, 50);` outside the event listener.

Comment: @Volune: this worked, and The first line drag is perfect, but the performance still decreases each time the line is dragged, much like what happened when I tried the setTimeout strategy.  Weird.  However, you did answer my question so if you answer I would pick it eventually, unless someone comes through with a solution to all my troubles.  Do you think I should ask another question about why the performance is decreasing dramatically?

Comment: I guess you should do another question (to keep this one focused on the `_.throttle` issue), if you can make it clear enough / provide enough code / provide fiddle. Performance problems may be hard to describe, good luck.

Comment: Post your `plothover` code.  I've done dragging stuff with flot before and haven't seen performance issues.  Here's a point drag example: http://plnkr.co/edit/GHiiJzh9mGY3Bpo7YPWU?p=preview

Comment: @Mark I actually just got home from work so that will have to wait until tomorrow but I will do that. I'm just a beginner actually so you may or may not find a lot of issues lol.  I will probably end up making a new topic as well, and I will link it here when I do.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Actually I just got orders to scrap this functionality from my program.  So there's no reason to worry about it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var throttled1 = _.throttle(singleLine, 50);
```

`throttled1` must be initialized oustide of the event listener, so it can track calls and timers internally, event after event.